Function signatures in vim/nvim for MSGraph module not showing despite various LSP plugins
I'm breaking my head trying to get function signatures/ parameter info showing up using Vim for the MSGraph pip module. This SDK is difficult to work with as the documentation is only generated for certain API calls and lacks a lot of meta information, so I need to check the code frequently to see what datatype methods expect, where they can be imported from and how these are structured. It is cumbersome to do so manually.
For example:
In order to check what the method to create a device compliance policy needs
client.device_management.device_compliance_policies.post()

I would go to .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/msgraph/generated/device_management/device_compliance_policies/device_compliance_policies_request_builder.py (the path of which I inferred from the function chain) and find out that there is an object called DeviceCompliancePolicy, then I would check the imports in that class to read the source for that to check what parameters this object needs or if there is an inherited object I should use and so on and on, tremendously inefficient. But the documentation doesn't really help, as lots of functions are simply not documented.
So in order to do that quicker, I'd like to see the function signature for this function. I have tried PyCharm and it works there! Nice, but I would like to setup my lovely Vim to do the same, shouldn't be too hard right?
Well, I've tried CoC using jedi, pyright and pylsp. All of them were able to find the definitions for classes such as DeviceCompliancePolicy or , but they can't find anything about post() from device_compliance_policies_request_builder.py.
For example using pyright, when trying to gd on post() gives only [coc.nvim] definition not found and when trying Kit doesnt show parameter info, bur rather: (function) post: Unknown.
I'm at my wits end, even tried LunarVim, just because I figured it might work OOTB for such a huge distribution of NeoVim which markets itself as an "IDE layer for NeoVim", but it's the same story there.
Does anyone have an idea on what goes wrong here, or rather what magic PyCharm employs to make this work? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding on how to use these features?
I gladly welcome any suggestions to improve my crooked workflow btw, especially if they're pertaining to MSGraph. I'm not happy with it. ;'(
